# Searching contents of text files on remote computers and exporting to excel file using powershell and export-excel

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-excel

I'm trying to search the contents of text files on remote computers from `computers.txt` which includes

```
Pc1
Pc2
Pc3
Pc4
```

And export it using `export-excel` PowerShell module
using this code:

```
$directory = $PSScriptRoot
$computers = Get-Content -Path $directory\computers.txt
$searchwords = 'word1','word2','word3'

Foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $path = "\\$computer\C$\test\logs"

    Foreach ($sw in $searchwords) {
        $excel = Get-Childitem -path $path -recurse -Include "*.txt" |
        Select-string -pattern "$sw" |
        Select-object pattern, linenumber, line, path |
        Export-excel $file -autosize -startrow 1 -tablename pattern -worksheetname "errors" -passthru
        
        $ws = $excel.workbook.worksheets['errors']
        $excel.save()
    }
}
```

The problem is that it will only export the contents of `pc4` which is the last in the `computers.txt` list.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the ```-append``` switch on ```export-excel```? Note you may have to remove the ```-passthru``` for this to work

Comment: @otter it did work thanks, and it worked with `passthru` as it caused many errors without it. Can you post the answer to select it as an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `-append` switch on `export-excel` will get this working.

It was added as part of the release on 10/30/2017 - https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel#whats-new-in-release-52